# error Method 'main' must be in a class 'Rextester'. can anyone explain

Tags: java, string

Method 'main' must be in a class 'Rextester'.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Sathya{
    String a,b;

    Sathya (String x,String y)
    {
        a=x;
        b=y;
    }
    Sathya ( Sathya x1,Sathya x2)
    {
        a=x1.a+" "+x2.a;
        b=x1.b+" "+x2.b;
    }
    void disp()
    {

        System.out.print(a+" "+b);
    }
```

}
         class Opcd
        {

```
        public static void main(String args [])
        {
            Sathya s1 =new Sathya("java", "india");
            s1.disp();
        }
    }
```

****error Method 'main' must be in a class 'Rextester'.****

Comment: You cannot declare a static method in a non static inner class. Since you probably never intended to make Opcd an inner class of Santhya why not follow the java conventions and declare classes in their own files instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, the compiler says: `The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type`. And there you have it.

You can only declare main method in the top level class, i.e. Sathya class, and not in inner class.